# I am trying to compare an input character from from a user to the first letters of an array structure

Tags: c

```
     #include <stdio.h>
     #include <stdlib.h>
     #include <string.h>

     typedef struct students {
       char Fname[10];
     } students_type;

     char letter;

     companies_type companies[10];

     int main() {

         printf("Please enter the first letter of a students name: ");
         scanf("%s", letter);
         result=0;
         for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
             if(strcmp(letter, students[i].Fname[0])==0)
             {
             printf("%c\n", students[i].Fname[0]);
             result++;
             }
             if(result==0)
             {
        printf("-1");
             }
         }
     }
```

When i compile the code the i get a response, segmentation fault (core dumped). the code is suppose to output the first letter of a name in the array if it matches the letter input by the user, otherwise it will print -1. The code would have scanned the the array Fname from a file first.

Comment: Code shown is incomplete. Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `scanf("%s", letter);` ==> begs at least one question, the answer to which we would already have with a proper [mcve]. Update your posted code. Related, `strcmp(letter, students[i].Fname[0])` treating that `Fname[0]` argument as a pointer to string, has a pungent code smell. Especially in conjunction with the later line, where `printf("%c\n", students[i].Fname[0]);` treats the same value as a single character.

Comment: I assume `students[i].Fname[0]` is a `char`? You cannot pass that to a string function. In fact, your compiler should have produced warnings for that. Also assuming `letter` is in fact a char array and not a single char then the condition should be `if(letter[0] ==  students[i].Fname[0])`. But that's just guess work since you have not shown complete code.

Comment: Is the full program what you need to answer this question?

Comment: Did you read the link we gave you? That explains what we need.

Comment: We miss the declaration of the variables of your code to give you the answer. I am pretty sure the problem is there.

Comment: I hope the updated code helps.

Comment: Where is the ```students``` array being initialized?

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdbool.h>
int main()
{
    char name[3][20]={"apple","orange","mango"}; //this is a string array with 3 items
    int i;
    bool result = false;
    char input;
    printf("Enter a letter\n");
    scanf("%c",&input);
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(input == name[i][0])//this checks whether input equals to the first letter of every element
        {
            printf("%c",name[i][0]);
            result = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(result == false)
    {
        printf("-1");
    }
    return 0;
}
```